# Convert a Numeric(19,0) Value to a DateTime

Tags: t-sql

I have a Numeric (19,0) field that has the value 1868570243000000 in it.

The DB documentation says the field is an "An EMR-generated ID that indicates the time an item was signed."

How can I convert that into a DateTime value?

I have tried something along these lines:

```
select dateadd(s, convert(bigint, 1868570243000) / 1000, convert(datetime, '1-1-1970 00:00:00'))
```

but I had to remove 3 of the zeroes before it would work.

AND ... it gives me this: *2029*-03-18 23:17:23.000

When I am expecting this: *2019*-03-18 23:17:23.000

The Month, Day and Time are correct - but it is 10 years in the future!!

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Epoch Time for current date is `1553023530` while you have a value of `1868570243` (a decade in the future).

You may want to validate your data and/or methodology here  [Epoch Converter](https://www.epochconverter.com/)

**Just for fun, try:**

```
Select OddValue   = dateadd(SECOND, 1868570243000 / 1000, '1970-01-01 00:00:00')
      ,EpochValue = dateadd(SECOND, 1552951043000 / 1000, '1970-01-01 00:00:00')
      ,Delta      = (1868570243000 - 1552951043000) / 1000
```

**You'll get**

```
OddValue                  EpochValue                Delta
2029-03-18 23:17:23.000   2019-03-18 23:17:23.000   315619200.000000
```

Comment: Hi John! Thanks for your help. I did run the sql you sent and saw what you meant. But my problem is not solved - possibly because I was not clear enough or precise enough in what I said.

Comment: When I run this sql on the value in the numeric(19,0) field, I get the correct date for the field. Is it possible to tweak this statement to give me a DateTime value instead of just a Date: Select Cast(DateAdd(d, (Cast(1868570243000000/1000000 As Int) / 3600 / 24), '1960') As Date) As DocDate

Comment: @Talay You certainly can use 1960-01-01, but will that impact your other data?   Seems odd having an Epoch of 1960.

Comment: No. My bad for not spotting it immediately. In this particular DB, 1960 is stipulated for all Numeric (19, 0) fields that are used as DateTime fields. I confess, I have never heard the term 'Epoch' in this context. I am an ex-English Literature professor so it was a bit of a mind warp for me trying to put the word 'Epoch' into the t-sql world!! Apologies, and Thanks again!!

Comment: @Talay No apologies.   This is the fun part.   I'm a former hotelier :)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you so much for your help @John Cappelletti! Sincerely appreciate it!

Here is the solution I was able to come up with using a combination of what you gave me and some other code I have used in the past:

```
Select DateAdd(SECOND, 1868570243000000 / 1000000, '1960') As Full_Time
```

This gives me what I was looking for.

Thanks again!