# Converting epoch seconds column to date time in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, epoch, dateadd

I have a column with epoch seconds (data type is `varchar`) that I need to convert to date time format. I'm having trouble using the `dateadd()` function.

```
UPDATE A
SET A.departure = DATEADD(s, departure, '1970-01-01 00:00:00')
FROM TABLE A
```

I'm getting this error:

> Argument data type varchar is invalid for argument 2 of dateadd function

Two questions:

1. Am I using the `dateadd()` function correctly?
2. What should I convert the column data type to in order for it to work? I tried to convert to `int`, but that did not work

Comment: Include a sample value of the column you'd like to convert, and the correct datetime you're trying to convert to.

Comment: Without sample data, it is hard know what "departure" is... Is it a true EPOCH in milliseconds ?   Take a peek at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55248494/convert-a-numeric19-0-value-to-a-datetime/55248711#55248711

Comment: DATEADD(s, departure, cast('1970-01-01 00:00:00' as datetime))

Comment: *"Argument data type varchar is invalid for argument 2 of dateadd function"* This error can't be more clear. `departure` is clearly a `varchar`. You can't "add" a `varchar` to a date. The 2nd parameter much be a numerical data type. If `departure` only contains numerical data types, you *need* to fix your design. If it doesn't only contain numerical values, how many second is `'abc'` seconds?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

It seems that your epoch time is stored, unfortunately, as a string value. Using `TRY_CAST` will allow you to convert the values that can be converted from strings to an integer that you can add using `DATEADD`.

If you have the option, it would be preferable to take that converted value and store it in a new column with a proper `DATE` or `DATETIME` data type so that you don't find yourself wrestling with strings again in the future.

```
UPDATE A
SET A.departure = DATEADD(SECOND, TRY_CAST(departure AS bigint), '1970-01-01 00:00:00')
FROM TABLE A
```

Actually, after typing that, updating that original column isn't a good idea at all. For values where `departure` can't be converted, the function will return `NULL` and you'll lose data. You'll need to do some validation here to avoid issues.

At the very least:

```
SELECT 
 *
FROM TABLE 
WHERE TRY_CAST(departure AS bigint) IS NULL;
```